# connect ETIMEDOUT 137.116.128.188:443 for bot FRAMEWORK, can be extended

Tags: botframework

So I have a request that is expected to run for at least 1 min. before it will give a response

To help aid user on not doing anything while my request is still running, I set some sendTyping activities:

For censoring production codes work sensitive information
, this is generally how my code looks like:

```
        var queryDone = "No";
        var xmlData = '';
        let soappy = soapQuery("123", "456", "789","getInfo");

        soappy.then(function (res) {
            queryDone = 'Yes';
            xmlData = res;
            console.log(xmlData);
        }, function (err) {
            queryDone = 'Timeout';
        })

        while (queryDone == 'No') {
            await step.context.sendActivity({ type: 'typing' });
        }
```

where `soapQuery()` is a function that sends and returns the POST request which looks like this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            }
            else {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    })
```

Problem comes because of this 1 minute response, (it's not really negotiable as the server requires at least 1 min to process it, due to large number of data and validation of my request).

Though after 1 minute, the console does print the response, sadly even before this, the bot already time out.
[image]

Any suggestion how to fix this, or extend time out of the bot?

I need the sendtyping activity so that user understands that the request is not yet done. And again, it really takes 1 minute before my request responds.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the reason that this happens is that HTTP requests work a little bit differently in the Bot Framework than you might expect. [Here's how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#http-details):

[image]

So basically, what's happening in your scenario is:

1. User sends HTTP POST
2. Bot calls your `soapQuery`
3. Bot starts sending Typing Indicators
4. `soapQuery` completes
5. Bot finally sends an HTTP Response to the HTTP POST from step #1, after the request has already timed out, which happens after 15 seconds

To fix this, I would:

1. Use [`showTypingMiddleware`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/showTypingMiddleware.ts) to send the typing indicator continuously and automatically until the bot sends another message (this gets rid of your blocking `while` loop)
2. Once `soapQuery` finishes, the bot will have lost context for the conversation, so your `soappy.then()` function will need to send a [proactive message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages). To do so, you'll need to [save a reference to the conversation prior to calling `soappy()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/bots/proactiveBot.js#L41), and then within the `then()` function, you'll need to [use that conversationReference to send the proactive message to the user](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L73).

Note, however, that the bot in the sample I linked above calls the proactive message after receiving a request on the `api/notify` endpoint. Yours doesn't need to do that. It just needs to send the proactive message using similar code. [Here's some more documentation on Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript)